# For lists, " TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list' "

Tags: python, list, loops, integer, typeerror

I am working in JupyterNotebook with Python. I have a code which generates a list of numbers based on given conditions.

Now, I have a list called "redshifts_1", which consists of 100 numbers (as shown below), and some other lists with much more elements (Total no. of elements in some lists are as large as 10,000).

```
The redshifts for catalogue-1 are :- 

[0.3937722601808016, 1.703021817075436, 1.2515371180948391, 1.5053325124962917, 1.502115429330706, 1.2118356690863377, 1.2988496170986443, 1.6985966516481232, 0.7369159231832616, 1.3075111404469402, 1.7617272259702865, 1.4808394580094588, 0.5323972302397728, 1.9973211387782088, 1.3029216433147919, 1.0085233340677626, 1.8414079299886306, 1.3909159680419836, 0.6360340058694971, 0.5307319530566388, 0.779599567199659, 0.8108097268360366, 1.948172304473729, 1.9039840566354964, 0.9567103038310576, 1.2735803415957225, 0.7314279569003197, 0.9543541927874786, 1.5230964347029654, 0.42328983674448745, 0.92140811114098, 1.1048044063491929, 1.715639755851784, 1.277941053310115, 0.43845687458051835, 0.9576157566166437, 1.4393796021310894, 0.746873456479457, 1.2297150292793202, 1.9999957272476108, 1.286278990748867, 0.5930746180462965, 1.7636147477365178, 1.949888615818666, 0.6507581654735037, 1.5709924984439847, 0.9913649234492812, 0.655930975747419, 0.8845467306776302, 1.6507678709343176, 1.7401295199278772, 1.5421483141406331, 1.8210661515912703, 1.2066751663108781, 1.1205764402029241, 1.9493994596120294, 1.6330582363674386, 1.1734560843570876, 1.0150055302151235, 1.1338054051197028, 1.0994042686860055, 1.818892318966621, 1.0527895873995665, 1.5822102562993432, 0.6161527817064048, 0.7361668925418363, 0.53114581980066, 1.7949239142737579, 1.7854507791642529, 1.3282158665324701, 0.8198529917312201, 0.39459306326555893, 0.8353189463882427, 0.9398892374526739, 1.8995159391364747, 1.8508889266416642, 0.8718037510991405, 1.0395264033920333, 1.4760617981265471, 0.7741084863240639, 1.2462063880016059, 1.1798441793675092, 0.2928789776987013, 1.0208435057651946, 1.3839605583706676, 1.1066285325951608, 1.8427506912912093, 1.8154950644610564, 1.1003630945250396, 1.6264146056566873, 0.7884080210223927, 0.6557738347311777, 0.7675592239101863, 1.4230013284907312, 1.4722059834147718, 1.8778290188957683, 1.8369804652884818, 1.5383531739442609, 1.7618601390442332, 0.28042590099864606]
```

Now, I want to calculate My parameters "luminosity distance" and "errors" for each of the elements of above list, and then return two separate lists - one list containing "luminosity distance" for each of respective redshift value, and one list containing "errors" value for each of respective redshift value.

My code is :-

1)

```
# H for each z 
def H(z):
    h = 0.7
    H0 = 299792458*h/(2.9979*3.085678*10**25)
    Ωm = 0.284
    return H0*(Ωm*(1+z)**3 + 1-Ωm)**0.5


# luminosity distance
def dL(z, H):
    c = 9.715611890800001e-18  # speed of light [Gpc/s]
    return (1+z) * c * quad(lambda Z: 1/H(Z), 0, z)[0]


# errors for the luminosity distance
def error(z, dL, H):
    return dL(z, H) * ( (0.1449*z - 0.0118*z**2 + 0.0012*z**3)**2 + (0.05*z)**2 )**(0.5)
```

2. 

```
def generate(events=0, redshifts=[], ideal=False):
        .
        .
        .
        (---- Some other code ------)
        .
        .
        .

    # get luminosity distance and error for specific redshifts
    
    if redshifts:
        .
        .
        (---- Some other code ------)
        .
        .

        distances = [dL(z, H) for z in redshifts]
        errors = [error(z, dL, H) for z in redshifts]
    

    return redshifts, distances, errors
```

3. 

```
redshifts_1 , Luminosity_distances_1 , errors_1 = generate(events=0, redshifts = [redshifts_1], ideal=False)
```

The code in block-1 is running correctly as needed (because it is used while generating that initial list shown in the beginning). But when I run the third block of code, I'm getting the following error -

```
<ipython-input-45-f3e8a26be905> in generate(events, redshifts, ideal)
     45 
     46 
---> 47         distances = [dL(z, H) for z in redshifts]
     48         errors = [error(z, dL, H) for z in redshifts]
     49 

<ipython-input-45-f3e8a26be905> in <listcomp>(.0)
     45 
     46 
---> 47         distances = [dL(z, H) for z in redshifts]
     48         errors = [error(z, dL, H) for z in redshifts]
     49 

<ipython-input-21-04ed5dc03e54> in dL(z, H)
      8 def dL(z, H):
      9     c = 9.715611890800001e-18  # speed of light [Gpc/s]
---> 10     return (1+z) * c * quad(lambda Z: 1/H(Z), 0, z)[0]
     11 
     12 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

What should I do ?

Comment: When you call `generate` it appears that you are wrapping `redshifts_1` in brackets. If `redshifts_1` is already a list, then this is likely what is causing your problem. Replace it with `redshifts_1 , Luminosity_distances_1 , errors_1 = generate(events=0, redshifts = redshifts_1, ideal=False)`. If that doesn't fix your problem, then post the value of `print(redshifts)` immediately before the line that throws the error.

Comment: @Craig     Removing the brackets worked great!  Thank you very much ! 